# javax.sound.sampled.Clip in Java stops working after a while

Tags: java, audio, clip

I've been using Java Clip for a project, but I've stumbled into a strange error. The incriminated piece of code is this, which should just play a sound reading it from the file named path

```java
    public static void playSound(String path)
    {
        logger.info("Playing " + path);
        Clip clip = null;
        try {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(path)));
            clip.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            System.err.println("error while playing " + path);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It should play a bunch of files, but clearly something weird happens. As you can see here, it plays successfully some sounds (I can also here them), but, all in a sudden, I get a LineUnavailableException while playing a file (in different runs, the file causing the error changes too), that I've already played:

```
21:35:42.478 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/01 Title Screen.wav
21:35:44.289 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/02 Stage Start.wav
21:35:47.114 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/03 Main BGM.wav
21:35:47.555 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:47.921 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:48.138 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX bomb in place.wav
21:35:48.297 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:48.663 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:49.026 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:49.392 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:50.126 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/explosion.wav
21:35:50.448 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX bomb in place.wav
21:35:50.510 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:50.876 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:51.242 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:51.609 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:52.429 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/explosion.wav
21:35:53.095 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:53.494 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:53.860 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:54.226 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:54.559 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/03 Main BGM.wav
21:35:54.592 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:54.959 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:55.326 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:55.693 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:56.059 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:56.228 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX bomb in place.wav
21:35:56.426 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:56.792 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:57.159 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:57.675 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:58.125 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:58.225 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/explosion.wav
21:35:58.492 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:58.858 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:59.226 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:59.594 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:35:59.960 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX bomb in place.wav
21:35:59.965 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:00.332 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:00.699 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:01.065 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:01.442 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:01.809 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:01.960 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/explosion.wav
21:36:02.009 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/03 Main BGM.wav
21:36:02.176 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:02.543 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:02.910 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:03.275 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:03.643 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:04.009 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:04.087 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX bomb in place.wav
21:36:04.376 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:04.776 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:05.142 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:06.009 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:06.075 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/explosion.wav
21:36:06.375 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:06.742 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
21:36:07.131 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO  app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer - Playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
error while playing sounds/Bomberman SFX horizontal.wav
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
        at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:484)
        at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:1241)
        at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:115)
        at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1038)
        at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1134)
        at app.jbomberman@1.0-SNAPSHOT/app.jbomberman.audio.AudioPlayer.playSound(AudioPlayer.java:95)
        ... the stack trace ...
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I've of course googled the error, and found out that errors like this can be caused by playing a sound file whose type is not supported by Clip (that's also what the error is telling me). However, in this case, clip fails when it's trying to play a sound that has already been played (so I know its type is supported). Might this be due to the fact that I'm playing too many sounds (some of which last only 0.5s) in too short time intervals (two sounds per seconds)? What could be the cause?

I'm running my app with OpenJDK 20 on a linux (Ubuntu) Workstation, if that might help.

Thanks in advance for your help!

BTW I've tried also to cache the files that I play (to avoid opening too many files), loading them only once, and providing clip.open() with a ByteArrayInputStream, without much success.

Answer (score 1):

The `clip.open` method takes in an argument of `AudioInputStream`, however in your `playSound` method you supply it a `BufferedInputStream`, instead use the `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream` method (which can take in File, InputStream, URL, and other useful types), in place of your `BufferedInputStream`.

[Clip.open Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#open-javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream-)

[AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream-java.io.File-)

Here's an example of some working code:

```java
public static void playSound(String path) {
        logger.info("Playing " + path);
        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(path)));
            clip.start();
        } catch(LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
            System.err.println("error while playing " + path);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Also, I know you considered caching the files by using a `ByteArrayInputStream`, however that still introduces the overhead of creating a new `Clip` each time you play the sound. Instead I'd recommend initializing a `Clip` object for every sound you have and passing that into the `playSound` method, you can then call `clip.setFramePosition(0)` and `clip.start()` to reset and play the sound again.

Comment: Sorry, but I simply copied the wrong piece of code. In the original one I used AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream, but I copied it wrong

Comment: @dVNE Darn, perhaps you could provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Now, having cached the Clip objects, it works fine

Comment: @dVNE That's good, glad you figured it out.